# Test asyncio.gather with pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have this function in main.py

```py
def tasks():
    await asyncio.gather(
        function_1(),
        function_2(),
        function_3()
    )
```

where functions function_1, function_2, function_3 are similar and their structure looks like this

```py
def function_1():
    while True:
        # do something
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

I would like to write unit tests for the function tests.
So I have a file tests/test_main.py and class in it

```
from main import tasks

@pytest.mark.asyncio
class TestTasks:
    @patch("main.asyncio.gather", new_callable=AsyncMock)
    @patch("main.function_3", autospec=True)
    @patch("main.function_2", autospec=True)
    @patch("main.function_1", autospec=True)
    async def test_tasks(
        self,
        mock_function_1: MagicMock,
        mock_function_2: MagicMock,
        mock_function_3: MagicMock,
        mock_gather: AsyncMock,
    ):
        await tasks()

        mock_function_1.assert_called_once_with()
        mock_function_2.assert_called_once_with()
        mock_function_3.assert_called_once_with()
        # Up to this point everything is ok, but I don't know what to put in this assertion
        gather.assert_awaited_once_with(???)
```

Also when I run pytest I get this error:
`sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncMockMixin._execute_mock_call' was not expected`

Comment: show the traceback

Comment: For the first question:

E           AssertionError: expected await not found.
E           Expected: gather()
E           Actual: gather(<coroutine object AsyncMockMixin._execute_mock_call at 0x7f7bcfb72f80>, <coroutine object AsyncMockMixin._execute_mock_call at 0x7f7bcfbd8890>, <coroutine object AsyncMockMixin._execute_mock_call at 0x7f7bcfbd8900>)

And second question:
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncMockMixin._execute_mock_call' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: format it properly in your question. also what is the point of testing `tasks`? all it does is call `asyncio.gather`. that would be like testing `asyncio.gather`.